# How can list of mat-list can be sorted by the user?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple list:

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let custom of filteredRows; let i = index">
      <mat-checkbox color="primary"  (click)="selectUnselectAll()">
          {{custom.fieldHebKey}}
      </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

1. Why doesn't the list look like a list (all items are arranged side by side)?
2. How can I add an option for the user to change the order of items?

For every item I need the option to move it up and down in the list. "Up" will move the item up and change the order of its default value, the same for "down".

### Here is an example of the list:

[image: Here is an example of the list]

Comment: Do you have the material style imported? Do you have any style that overrides global element selectors like li or ul ...

Comment: 1.-if you want a "row distribution" enclosed the mat-checkbox inside a `<div>` - mat-checkbox is display:in-line or add style display:block. 2.- to order simply order the filteredRows array (but not use any pipe)

Comment: @Eliseo thank you. can you give me an example for doing number 2?

Comment: it's only sort the filteredRows, if you has a variable "key" and your array is an array of object: `this.filteredRows=this.filteredRows.sort((a:any,b:any)=>a[this.key]>b[this.key]?1:a[this.key]<b[this.key]?-1:0)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes to your code as below:

```
<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="selectUnselectAll($event)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let custom of filteredRows | orderBy: 'fieldHebKey'" [value]="custom.fieldHebKey">
        {{custom.fieldHebKey}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Please let me know if any help required.

Comment: where you get the orderBy pipe? NOTE: Is a bad idea use a pipe to order a list (it's very expensive in terms of efficency, better a simple function that sort the array)

Comment: where is the implement of orderby pipe?

Comment: I need that in every item will be 2 option up and down..up will move the item up and change the order of its default value, the same for down

Comment: its seemes very bad, as a list without option to choose